# How to deal with people/colleagues who speak/show more than they really know

Tags: work-environment

How do I deal with people at workplace who show/speak more than they really know or have really done to draw the attention of the manager?

One way I have experienced is to be patient and allow the work to speak for me but that requires lot of patience and time. Please give some insights into what other ways can I deal with this.

Comment: Don't assume they are drawing the attention of the manager in a good way. Focus on your own performance. You can answer questions and share information and still withhold your ideas.

Comment: Do you get the feeling that your manager is falling for this?

Comment: Give a thief enough rope and he will hang himself.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I deal with people at workplace who show/speak more than they really know or have really done to draw the attention of the manager?

If attempts at patience and normal diplomacy fail to improve the situation, then elaborate on a particular area that you know they are lacking the skills and/or knowledge; not in a way that is meant to be embarrassing to them, but to highlight the holes in their skills or knowledge gaps. When you expound on an area people lay claim to knowledge or expertise they can't back up, more often than not their sudden silence will contrast their prior show boasting and people will begin to see they may actually be the weakest link on the team. Just be sure to do so tactfully and not out of ill will.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have also noticed a general behavior that a person would try to understand something from us in person/privately and then speak to the manager or in public as if it was his/her original idea. How to deal with this. If I don't answer in private, it would be thought of as not sharing information.

Answer (score 1):

You are in a political game whether you want to be or not and not speaking up first is a losing move. Your work speaks for itself 0% of the time without you speaking up for it. No one else will know what you did if you don't speak up.

You need to make sure to make yourself visible. You need to make sure that others are aware of what you do.

Letting people take credit in public for your work is also a losing move unless the person is your boss. Speak up and say it was your idea. But it is easiest if you present the idea publicly first so the other person doesn't even have a chance to take credit.

Please do yourself a favor and get some books on office politics.

Comment: Any book recommendation?